# Do I have too many queries for lookup tables and can anyone suggest an alternative?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently building a codeigniter application that handles a specific type of mammal. When a user is adding a new record (mammal), they are given lists of 'breed types', 'genders', etc. Those are stored in separate database tables.

Currently, to get these, I have separate functions such as:

```
$this->Mammal->get_list_of_breeds()
$this->Mammal->get_list_of_genders()
```

Each of these calls a query, there may be up to 7 or 8 more different lookups for me to query. Does anyone know if this will significantly slow down my application or cause too many queries on the database. For the most part, the max number of records in any individual table is under 300 records.

Is there a better way I can be doing this by consolidating the queries into a single function and using php to split the lookup fields?

Any ideas or thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A thought suddenly came to me. Could i just put all the lookup tables in one single table with a type field? ( type being 'breed', 'gender', etc. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to take some of the smaller sets of options and put them in arrays, especially if they cannot be changed by the user. Gender, for example, could probably just be in an array. As far as I know, there are only two options. If there are any other similar option sets you could make those arrays too.

But, even 300 records is not a huge amount of data. I take it you aren't building the next Facebook, so just making several clean queries to get the options you need probably won't be a big deal.

Personally, I wouldn't put it all in one table. Big generic tables just seem kind of hokey, and you would still be getting the same amount of data. You could have separate tables and accomplish the same thing by UNIONing the queries.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented yourself, yes indeed you should put everything into one table...

So you'd have a table called mammals

And then you'd have the fields: gender, breeds etc...

Now this is a lot easier when programming in php since now you can do one query and then display everything, like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `mammals`";
$query_exec=mysql_query($query);

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query_exec))
{
print "gender: ".$result['gender']." breed: ".$result['breed'];
}
```

Little explanation:
The query gets everything from the table called mammals
Then the while just continues as long as there are still results in the array
The fetch array puts the data in the variable and every field can be read by $result[]

I know this is not a very clear explanation, but my mind also isn't the cleares at this late hour :/